# Redirect If REQUEST_URI begins with something

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two subdomains `api.example.net` and `www.example.net`. I want to redirect from `api.example.net` to `www.example.net` if the `REQUEST_URI` doesn't begin with `/v1/` (e.g. `/v1/token`, `/v1/status/update`).

My configuration file inside the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` is like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v1/
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I tried

```
petra@petra-laptop:~$ curl -XGET -k 'https://api.example.net/test'
```

it returned

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.example.net/test">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at api.example.net Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

which is what I expected.

But when I tried

```
petra@petra-laptop:~$ curl -XGET -k 'https://api.example.net/v1/token'
```

it returned

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.example.net/index.php">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at api.example.net Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

I expected it just pass to `https://api.example.net/v1/token`.

I tried the code here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, it returned what I expected.

What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

The project is using Yii Framework, so inside the `/var/www` there is this `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in your system?

Comment: In the directory `/var/www` you mean? Yes, I do. Let me update above `.htaccess` code.

Comment: Do you have `VirtualHost` entry in your .htaccess file?

Comment: That part, I don't really understand. I'm kind of new with Apache. As you can see in the `.htaccess` there is `VirtualHost` tag.

Comment: `VirtualHost` actually isn't even allowed in .htaccess

Comment: Ouch sorry, it's a file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. my bad, i'm new to this.

Comment: Move your rule from `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `.htaccess` just below `RewriteBase` line and see how it behaves.

Comment: nope, still return the same. for further details, the `www.example.net` and the `api.example.net` is pointing to the same codebase `/var/www`.

Comment: Your code works fine in my apache! Does it work if you disable the .htaccess file in you yii project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the token needs to be handled by your framework (or in other words: the rule in your `.htaccess` *must* match).

I am guessing (but not 100% sure), that during the next pass-through, the url is matched against the rule in your virtual-host again. Because the url then is `index.php` instead of `v1/token`, the rule in your virtualhost matches. To make sure the rule only matches the original url (the one in the request), use `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^(GET|POST)\ /v1/
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Because this is in the main config file, you'll have to restart Apache for any changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try that one (I hope I'm not missing something):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^v1/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you place it in vhost then you may have to restart Apache for any changes to take effect.

If you place it in .htaccess file (you can do it at least for tests), you should place it before "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f".

**EDIT:** I think I got it! **You'll say it didn't work** (again), because you are testing with a URL which doesn't points to a file or directory (!!!) and then when the file/directory doesn't exists, the request is redirected again to the index.php.

I tested on my end on a subdomain+another domain with a WP installation and it seems if the file doesn't exist I'm getting redirected to the main domain (where WP is installed and configured). When I use an existing file, then the redirect works just fine!

If it didn't work, do you have an option to test it on another server or on the same server, but using another document root, where you'll have just the above rewrites to test them separated from the other existing rules?

Let me know which are the results!

Comment: this doesn't work if i tried `api.example.net/v1/test` it will redirect to `www.example.net/v1/test`.

Answer (score -1):

I missed your mistake, you did !^/v1/

It should be ! ^/v1/:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.example.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^/v1/:
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.net%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    <Directory /var/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You mean `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/v1/:`? Using this one, the `https://api.example.net/v1/token` will go to `https://www.example.net/v1/token` instead of `https://www.example.net/index.php`. `https://api.example.net/test` still goes to `http://example.net/test`.